# store web service data to shared preference

Tags: android, json, web-services, sharedpreferences

. why every vote negatively .. am new to android ;(  . your soution may help some other to..
I have an application. at the time of login, i want to store the data to shared preference.

I am trying to save data from the server into `Shared Preferences`. I am receiving data from server successfully

I tried but some errors are there

```
{"Login":"Success","Login Details":[{"name":"abc","place":"abcdd","cityname":"asdf"}]}
```

**code is:**

```
  public class login extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    InputStream ins;
    String status,details, result, s = null, data = "", js;
    int ss;
    int responseCode;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        ArrayList al;
        try {
            URL url =new URL(BuildConfig.url);

            String param = "username=" + uname + "&password=" + pass2;
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(15000);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            bw.write(param);
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();

            responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            }
            data = sb.toString();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);

            status = json.getString("Login");


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.i("MalformedURLException", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("IOException", e.getMessage());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.i("JSONException", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

            String status1 = status.trim();


            if (status1.equals("Success")) {

                try {
                    JSONObject  jsonObject = new JSONObject(status1);
                    JSONArray array=jsonObject.getJSONArray("Login Details");

                    for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++){


                        jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);

                        name= jsonObject.getString("name");
                        place= jsonObject.getString("place");
                        cityname = jsonObject.getString("cityname");


                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                editor.putString("name", name);
                editor.putString("place", place);
                editor.apply();
                Toast.makeText(Login.this,name+":"+cityname+":"+mobileno,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else {
                 Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Username or Password is Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }



        }

    }
```

Comment: where are errors?

Comment: my code is right??

Comment: If you are getting expected output then it is right. if any errors then explain

Comment: i didnt get the result, when i toast 3 values o/p is null:null:null

Comment: i change the actual values here ,forget change toast values

Comment: same o/p in toast null:null:null

Comment: try printing the log inside for loop Log.d("value",name+""+cityname+""place); just for test that values are there or not.

Comment: i add toast inside try.. but it didnt go to try block why??

Comment: Not going in try means response is not success.

Comment: First parse the json properly and print logs to check that response.

Comment: ok ,  it is enter in to if loop, toast is working there but try is not

Comment: try my answer once

Comment: ok  i will try ....

Comment: toast o/p is still  null:null

Answer (score 2):

Your 'JSONArray' Consist of only one JSONObject and your using loop

```
try {
                    JSONObject  jsonObject = new JSONObject(status1);
                    JSONArray array=jsonObject.getJSONArray("Login Details");
//"Login Details":[{"name":"abc","place":"abcdd","cityname":"asdf"}] only one object 
                    for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++){


                        jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);

                        name= jsonObject.getString("name");
                        place= jsonObject.getString("place");
                        cityname = jsonObject.getString("cityname");


                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I hope you understand it and this hint can work for you
And Please make your using same variable in parsing and printing also

Comment: @Avinash the logindetail jsonArray has only as one jsonobject whic it self has 3 terms name , place , cityname
If you have any confusion in reading jsonArray and JsonObject learn what are actually these terms

Answer (score 2):

First of all `status` is not a json object its a string ,  make sure your doinbackground returns proper result and then use `JSONObject  jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);` instead of `JSONObject  jsonObject = new JSONObject(status1);`